# finding device Location with the help of GPS in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

How do i find my device location with the help of GPS using Xamarin android?please explain me the full code with each file in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this example. http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

This solution works for me.